# Issue facing with the close button tagged at the right edge of a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div of id #feedback. When i click on it another div of id #feedback-form slide down.Along with this a close button is also tagged at the right edge of the #feedback div.

This is not working.

along with this i also want that when i click on the close button the #feedback-form div should slide Up and the close button should disappear.

But that doesn't work out. Please provide some solution.

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ncR2L/

js:

```
$('#feedback').click(function(){
    $('#feedback-form').slideDown();
    $('#feedback').find('i').show();    
}); 

$('#feeback').find('i').click(function(){
    $('#feedback').find('i').hide();
    $("#feedback-form").slideUp();
});
```

css:

```
#feedback{
width:120px;
height:40px;
cursor:pointer;
background:#36F;
}
#feedback i{
float:right;
display:block;
position:relative;
top:-5px;
right:-5px;
color:red;
background:white;
display:none;
}
#feedback-form{
display:none;
position:absolute;  
margin-top:30px;
}
#feed-form{
width:400px;
text-align:center;
}
#feed-form fieldset{
border: 0 none;
padding: 20px;  
background:rgba(96,0,0,0.8);
width:80%;
}
#feed-form fieldset input,textarea{
padding:7px;
width: 80%;
border:2px solid #ccc;
margin-bottom:15px;
color: #2C3E50;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="feedback"><span>Feedback</span><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    <div id="feedback-form">
      <form method="post" id="feed-form">
      <fieldset>
      <h2> Tell Us What You Think</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
      <textarea rows="4" cols="40" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
      </fieldset>
      </form>

      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code. There's a reason SO doesn't allow you to just post a fiddle link, please don't try to work around it.

Comment: what do you mean by "close button tagged"? there is no close button in your fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you wrote `#feeback` instead of `#feedback` in your jQuery.

Then, when you click the i element, which is also in #feedback, you are going to trigger the slideDown, which is unwanted. To avoid that, use `e.stopPropagation()`, like so:

```
$('#feedback').click(function(){
    $('#feedback-form').slideDown();
    $('#feedback').find('i').show();    
}); 

$('#feedback').find('i').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#feedback').find('i').hide();
    $("#feedback-form").slideUp();

});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ncR2L/1/)